# Function works but fails in Jest test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm new to Jest, just playing around with some tests for existing function at the moment.
I have a function which takes an array of data (from a JSON file) and maps it to specific positions, plotting points.

This is the function plotPoints:

```
function plotPoints(data) {
  console.log(data.subset[0]);
  const sub0 = data.subset[0];
...
```

plotPoints takes the JSON data as an argument.  The function works because it logs the data correctly in the console and the other functionality works as expected.

But the test always fails:

plotPoints.test.js

```
import plotPoints from '../functions/plotPoints';
const dataSrc = require('../../public/data/jsonfile.json');

test('it finds the plot data', () => {
  expect(plotPoints(dataSrc)).toBeDefined();
});
```

Returning this error:

```
it finds the plot data

TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

  3 | // takes raw JSON data and builds a big object with matching joint pairs
  4 | function plotPounts(data) {
> 5 |   const sub0 = data.subset[0];
    |                ^
  6 |


  at plotPoints (src/functions/plotPoints.js:5:16)
  at Object.<anonymous>.test (src/tests/plotPoints.test.js:5:10)
```

I thought that perhaps the function was running in the test before jsonfile.json was loaded so I tried writing an asynchronous test based on the Jest docs:

```
test('it finds the correct joints', done => {
  function callback(input) {
    expect(input).toBeDefined();

    done();
  }
  mapJoints(callback(dataSrc));
});
```

But this made no difference. Is there any reason why the function has no trouble finding in the `data.subset[0]` array but not in the tests?

Comment: Have you stepped through the test code with a debugger?

Comment: When you do a `require` you may also need the `.default` at the end. The comment-posted-as-answer also suggests using a normal `import`--but checking your assumptions is *always* the first step, e.g., make sure you're operating on the data you think you are.

Comment: What happened is I was actually passing a specific segment of the JSON file into the actual function but no the test- duh.  Always be sure your tests are actually testing the params your functions take! I should probably delete this question, eh?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if `dataSrc` is defined?

Try replacing the require with:

```
import dataSrc from '../../public/data/jsonfile.json'
```